# Drawing multipe items in svg g elements using d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I want to draw three different shapes collected inside a g element. I want to draw text, line and a graph. The problem im having with the code below is that the text is shown but the line does not show. It is drawn and I can see it in the source but it is not visible on the screen. What am I missing here?

```
  //Bind data to a new g element
  line = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(source)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr({
    "transform": function(d,i){ return "translate(50 " + (height - 50 + 15 * i) + ")"}
  });

  line.append("text")
  .text(function(d,i){
    return d.name;
  });

  line.append("line")
  .attr({
    "opacity" : 1,
    "stroke-width" : 2,
    "stroke" : "blue",
    "class" : "crisp",
    "x1" : function (d) { return vfTimelineScale(d.start); },
    "y1" : function (d,i) { return (height - 50 + 15 * i); },
    "x2" : function (d) { return vfTimelineScale(d.stop); },
    "y2" : function (d,i) { return (height - 50 + 15 * i); },
  })
```

Comment: Are the `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` values what you expect?

Comment: <g transform="translate(50 450)"><text>A-Module</text><line opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke="blue" class="crisp" x1="100" y1="450" x2="700" y2="450"></line></g>

Comment: This is what gets printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already positioning through the transformation, I presume you don't need the lines to be `450` px offset vertically from the text. Change the formula to something such as...

```
"x1" : function (d) { return vfTimelineScale(d.start); },
"y1" : 50,
"x2" : function (d) { return vfTimelineScale(d.stop); },
"y2" : 50
```

You will need to change the `50` value to suit your needs of course.